# LINQ query to ado.data entity model selecting more than one column in c#

Tags: linq, ado.net-entity-data-model

```
ECommerceAdoEntities oContext = new ECommerceAdoEntities();           
var lstnames = from c in oContext.tbl_ShippingProfile  select c.Name;
```

When I try to run a linq query against a ADO.net entity data model data source and return more than one column (c.Name,c.ID) it gives me error in C#

But in VB I am able to do it.

```
Dim adoDataEntity As New ECommerceAdoEntities()
Dim lstAdoSource = From c In adoDataEntity.tbl_ShippingProfile Select c.Name, c.ID
```

Any idea why?

Comment: I suspect the VB.NET compiler is implicitly converting `Select c.Name, c.ID` to `Select New With { .Name = c.Name, .ID = c.ID }`, which is similar what you would write in C#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 var lstnames = from c in oContext.tbl_ShippingProfile  
                select new 
                {
                   c.Name,
                   c.ID
                 };
```